# Teradata Dates with a day and week

Tags: teradata

I have a User, I have records with a Date Timestamp it includes Day hour second, I want to for each User to count the number of hours they were in the system per that day, calculating the first record of the day and the last record of the day, then I want to do this for the week, so Column 1 = # of hours I was in the system for the day, column 2 = number of hours I am in the system for that week.
I know there is a simple way to do this and I am over looking the simplest thing i think.

```
Assigned To: = End User
```

Start Date = Date and Time for the record,
some records have a start date and time,
some have a start date and an end date.
If first record is 8/2/2021 8:43:49 AM then this is the first record,
if the last record for that day is 8/2/2021 3:52:58 PM
Calculate the hours and minutes between first record and last record.

```
Task    StartDate   EndDate ASSIGNEDTO
Effectuation    8/2/2021 7:16       frank.author
Case Review 8/2/2021 7:36   8/2/2021 7:38   james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 7:38   8/2/2021 10:46  james.stevo
Effectuation    8/2/2021 7:54       frank.author
Case Review 8/2/2021 8:00   8/2/2021 8:22   james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 8:23   8/2/2021 10:46  james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 8:33   8/2/2021 10:47  james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 8:38   8/2/2021 10:47  james.stevo
Effectuation    8/2/2021 8:51       frank.author
Case Review 8/2/2021 9:04       james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 9:18   8/2/2021 13:10  james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 9:30       james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 9:53       james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 10:43  8/2/2021 20:50  james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 11:03  8/2/2021 20:50  james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 11:06      james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 11:07      james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 11:14      james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 11:38      james.stevo
Effectuation    8/2/2021 11:38      frank.author
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 12:03  8/2/2021 20:51  james.stevo
Case Review 8/2/2021 12:07      james.stevo
Manual Outreach 8/2/2021 12:23  8/2/2021 20:51  james.stevo
```

Comment: What's your problem, getting start/end date or calculating the duration between?

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your description of your data is very vague. Please post sample data so we can understand what your data looks like and what you are trying to do to it.

Comment: sorry I should be more clear long day:

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post and a similar on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298511/teradata-min-and-max-dates-find-the-employees-start-date-and-time-and-end-date-a)

```
select 
   AssignedTo
  ,cast(StartDate as date) -- for each day
  ,min(StartDate) as minDate
  ,max(EndDate) as MaxDate
  ,MaxDate - minDate hour to minute -- difference max-min
from myTable
group by 1,2
```

Edit based on your answer:

```
WITH users_In_Out AS
 (
   Select AssignedTo as UserID, 
      Cast((STARTDATE) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
      min(STARTDATE) as minDate, 
      max(ENDDATE) as MaxDate ,
      (MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
      'WorkflowLog' as Source
   From WorkflowLog
   Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
   and  ENDDATE Is Not NULL
   group by 1,2

   Union All
   ---- Task Completed
   Select CREATEDBY as UserID, 
      Cast((AUDITDATETIME) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
      min(AUDITDATETIME) as minDate, 
      max(AuditDateTime) as MaxDate ,
      (MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
      'Audit' as Source
   From Audit
   Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
   and  AuditDateTime Is Not NULL
   group by 1,2

   Union All

   --- Task and Queue completed
   Select CurrentAssignedTo as UserID, 
      Cast((UpdateDatetime) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
      min(UpdateDatetime) as minDate, 
      max(UpdateDatetime) as MaxDate ,
      (MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
      'CaseMetadata' as Source
      From CaseMetadata
      Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
      and  UpdateDatetime Is Not NULL
      group by 1,2 
 )
Select UserID, 
   UpdateDatetime,
   min(minDate) as minDate, 
   max(MaxDate) as MaxDate ,
   max(MaxDate) - min(minDate) hour to minute as htm
From users_In_Out
group by 1,2
```

Of course, calculating `htm` and `source` in the UNIONs is not needed for the final Select and could be removed.

Comment: dnoeth, I want to say thank. its the simple stuff that evidently gets me from staring at this screen for 12 hours a day probably. been following you for years and have used quite a few of your post over the years, just wanted to say thanks for all you do sir.

Comment: IS there a way to reset this everytime the data changes? Assigned to: Start Date and Time, End Date and Time for each day and assignedto?

Comment: `cast(StartDate as date)` is already doing it :-)

Comment: So how would you do this for: Employee, Date (TimeStamp(3)), and get a start and end date for each day for each employee?  ''' Select CREATEDBY, 
AUDITDATETIME,
min(AUDITDATETIME) as minDate, 
max(AuditDateTime) as MaxDate 
From vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit
group by 1,2 '''

Comment: `Select CREATEDBY, cast(AUDITDATETIME as date), min(AUDITDATETIME) as minDate, max(AuditDateTime) as MaxDate From vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit group by 1,2`

Comment: My problem is i dont get the results i need.                                                             
What I want is: combine these 3      s/b                                                                                                                  
Joe 10/31/20 10:03:38am - 10/31/20205:22pm  07.31.66
UserID minDate                 MaxDate                         htm
joe 10/31/2020 10:03 AM 10/31/2020 4:51 PM 06:48:00
joe 10/31/2020 10:56 AM 10/31/2020 11:02 AM 00:06:00
joe 10/31/2020 10:56 AM 10/31/2020 5:22 PM 06:26:00

Comment: What's *07.31.66*? If you get 3 rows instead of 1 you don't run my query, there must be something else

Answer (score 0):

I put the 3 tables together
and was trying to get the min and max for the user,
sometimes there are 3 records for a user,
min date would be first login or min date and last maxdate would be last logout

```sql
Select AssignedTo as UserID, 
Cast((STARTDATE) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
min(STARTDATE) as minDate, 
max(ENDDATE) as MaxDate ,
(MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
'WorkflowLog' as Source
From WorkflowLog
Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
and  ENDDATE Is Not NULL
group by 1,2
Union All
---- Task Completed
Select CREATEDBY as UserID, 
Cast((AUDITDATETIME) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
min(AUDITDATETIME) as minDate, 
max(AuditDateTime) as MaxDate ,
(MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
'Audit' as Source
From Audit
Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
and  AuditDateTime Is Not NULL
group by 1,2
Union All
--- Task and Queue completed
Select CurrentAssignedTo as UserID, 
Cast((UpdateDatetime) as Date) as UpdateDatetime,
min(UpdateDatetime) as minDate, 
max(UpdateDatetime) as MaxDate ,
(MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm,
'CaseMetadata' as Source
From CaseMetadata
Where INTERNALID Is Not Null
and  UpdateDatetime Is Not NULL
group by 1,2     Select UserID, 
Cast(UpdateDatetime as date)as UpdateDatetime,
min(minDate) as minDate, 
max(MaxDate) as MaxDate ,
(MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm
From users_In_Out
group by 1,5,2
```

Comment: You get three rows because a user has rows in all three tables. If you want hte min/max over those three table you must wrap it in a Derived Table/CTE and add another min/max on top of it.

Comment: Thats correct and I thought thats what I was doing: '''---- Pull It All Together
```
Select UserID, 
--- Source,
--- Cast(UpdateDatetime as date)as UpdateDatetime,
min(minDate) as minDate, 
max(MaxDate) as MaxDate ,
(MaxDate) - (minDate) hour to minute as htm
From users_In_Out
Where UserID = 'joe'
group by 1,4,2 ```

Comment: So end results I am trying to get and you would think this is simple, user name min and max date from the 3 or 2 records per user, sounds pretty a b c. but no i have to screw it up evidently.

Comment: Now I see, there's a final Select after the Unions, this is not valid syntax. If `users_In_Out` is supposed to be the unioned rows you must wrap them in a Derived Table or CTE. I edit my answer to show using a CTE.